# How to convert percentage greater than 100% to 100%?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to calculate weightage percentage of two percentages with each weighted 50% each.

Assume my two percentages are (A, B). fixed denominator values, Now I want to convert this convert excess above 100% percent values to 100, then calculate weightage percentage of these values.

Example:

A = (5/3)*100 = 166.6% ;

B = (5/3)*100 = 166.6%

(here both A and B denominator is fixed)

first convert A, B percentage to 100
then finally, I want to calculate the weighted percentage of both using this formula:

( (166.6)*0.5+(166.6)*0.5 )  should be less than 100%.

Im trying to write this equation into my python code to calculate percentage between elements given manual weightage to each.

I have gone thru few videos and blogs which are explaining to converting to decimal and other method to multiply by 100.
but I'm unable to convert those into code, any simple approach to calculate this.

any help will much appreciated, Thanks alot.

ref: I tried

[https://www.wikihow.com/Convert-an-Improper-Fraction-to-Percent#:~:text=About%20This%20Article&text=To%20convert%20an%20improper%20fraction%20to%20percent%2C%20start%20by%20dividing,the%20end%20of%20your%20answer](https://www.wikihow.com/Convert-an-Improper-Fraction-to-Percent#:%7E:text=About%20This%20Article&text=To%20convert%20an%20improper%20fraction%20to%20percent%2C%20start%20by%20dividing,the%20end%20of%20your%20answer).

Comment: Unclear exactly what you're trying to accomplish - you can rescale your value of 166.6% to any other percentage you want, but it's not really a meaningful value if it's not on some meaningful scale. Are you saying 166.6% is the top end of your scale, and should map to 100%? Or is there some other scale, that perhaps goes up to 200% by which you want to rescale your 166.6%? As an aside, you may be better off summing the counts in A and B and then computing an overall percentage, since if A and B have different counts, a simply average of percentages won't weight them properly.

Comment: @NuclearWang Assume there's a variable(X) that each user can have and that takes the value between 0 and infinite. I want to give a percentage value to each user variable X and that percentage should increase based on their value of variable X but should stay under 100%. (i.e., if guy A have X=100 and guy B have X = 50 the guy A whose X=100 is greater than guy B variable X. So, guy A should get more percentage than guy B. The problem is variable X can take any value range from 0 to infinite.)

Answer (score 1):

You can clamp a value between $0$ and $100$ with $$\min(\max(p,0),100)$$

Or just $$\min(p,100)$$

If your numbers are always positive, there may also exist a clamp function on python (I do not know) like $\operatorname{clamp}(p,0,100)$.

In case your percentage is represented by a decimal value in $[0,1]$ (e.g $18\ \%=0.18$) use $\min(p,1)$ instead.

So you'll get $$\min(p_1,100)\times C_1+\min(p_2,100)\times C_2$$

Comment: If we use this there will be a loss of information by scaling. suppose think two guys A & B having 150% and 80%, here guy A worked hard more than normal, i want to give more weightage to A than B.

Comment: In this case you can clamp after the weighted average $\min(p_1C_1+p_2C_2,100)$ but if it is for sharing justice it might be better to do $100\times\dfrac{p_1C_1+p_2C_2}{max(p1,p2)}$

Comment: Can you explain what C here mean? I want the percentage restrict to individual. Sir, can you take a look at this example also (i.e., if guy A have X=100(number of skills) and guy B have X = 50(number of skills) the guy A whose X=100 is greater than guy B variable X=50. So, guy A should get more percentage than guy B and percentage should stay below 100% (I don't know how to do this). The problem is variable X can take any value range from 0 to n number of skills (I don't have a predefined max value))

Comment: $C_i$ are the weight coefficients, here $C_1=C_2=0.5$ from your question. I think my last formula is ok for your problem as I understand it.